# Access data produced in a pod from a different pod in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ipc

I have a pod, called pod1 that runs a function which produces an array with random unordered integer elements and have also a service for this pod.
In addition, in the same cluster i have an other pod, called pod2 which runs a sorting function.

The pod1 has the following python code:

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

numbers= [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 2, 8]


@app.route('/numbers')
def get_numbers():
   return jsonify(incomes)

if __name__=="__main__":
   app.run(port='8080', debug=True)
```

Also the deployment file of the above pod is the following:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flaskapp
  labels:
    app: flaskapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flaskapp
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flaskapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flaskapp
        image: application:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flaskapp
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: flaskapp
```

In addition i have also another pod whi acts like a client and has the folloowing code:

```
import requests

x = requests.get('http://flaskapp:8080/numbers')
print(x.text)
```

in the http the flaskapp is the name of the service of pod1.

So when i apply the deployment file of pod2, the client pod is running succesfully but when i use the kubectl logs for that pod in order to see the expected output, nothing happens.

Is the definition of the requests.get('http://flaskapp:8080/numbers') correct? What i am doing wrong?

Comment: When creating the service you must have appointed a port that is exposed on pod1. What is behind that port? The simplest thing you can do is create an HTTP API that returns that array to its caller.

Comment: Let's say that the pod1 have a code something like this:

`from flask import Flask,jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

numbers = [1,2,4,7,5,9,0]


@app.route('/numbers')
def get_incomes():
  return jsonify(numbers)

If i have a service for this pod with a specific port. 
In order to have acces to the returned data should i call the service i defined previously with the cluster_i:port from the pod2?

Comment: You should edit your question with that example, but yes. You can use any Python HTTP library (eg `requests`) to grab those numbers from the defined service at that port.

Comment: Of course there are many correct answers. If you require multiple consumers or multiple producers it can pay off to use a different communication pattern such as a message broker (RabbitMQ, mosquitto, ...) or a shared data structure (Redis).

Comment: In this http library, lets say requests i ll give the service, like that:
x = requests(cluster_ip:port)?

Comment: On the service, `port` is the port number on which it listens, while `targetPort` is the port number it connects to on the **backing Pods**. You need to connect to `http://flaskapp:8000/numbers` then.

Comment: Yes you are right i correct it and now it occures the error : requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='flaskapp', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /numbers (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fdcd1e51540>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

Comment: You seem to still be connecting to port 8080?

Comment: I corrected the port to 8080 in my yaml file, so the new url should be http://flaskapp:8080/numbers right?

Comment: Yes. How was I supposed to know that?

Comment: Actually i made a typo, so i corrected my yaml file and set the port to 8080 so now it should work, but it doesnt because it occurs this error..

Comment: Test first from a standalone Pod with `curl`.

Comment: i ran curl flaskapp:8080/numbers
i am getting "Failed to connect flaskapp port 8080 :  Connection Refused"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245200/discussion-between-botje-and-zimr).

Answer (score 2):

It would help by using the correct terms in your question. A pod is simply an instance of a service and there are usually more than 1 related to the same service. When you are talking about 2 pods, it sounds like you are talking about two separate services, for example `Processer` and `RandomNumberGenerator` or something.

In microservices, services should only talk to each other via their published ports, this restricts implementation details to the service and works correctly with the way that cluster orhcestrators work (e.g. ephermeral pods, erroring pods etc.).

In your case, as @botje already suggested, if the request is synchronous, the second service can ask the first service for the array of numbers explicitly (send a request to the service using internal DNS) and process the results. If it is asynchronous, then you could use something like a queue and put the numbers into it, to have the processor take the list of numbers from the queue and process it. You would have to build the queue, it is not part of Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have:

- Pod `generator`, which exposes a Flask app on port 8080
- Service `generatorSvc`, which targets the `generator` Pod and exposes port 8080 as well
- Pod `client`,

then in `client` you can use

```
r = requests.get('http://generatorSvc:8080/numbers')
```

EDIT Since your service has `port: 8000`, you should connect to `http://generatorSvc:8000/numbers` instead.

Comment: I understand you concept but it doesnt work for some reason. I updated my post above with all my logic and codes. Could you please check it and suggest me what i am doing wrong? Thaanks!!

Comment: See edit. Next time please add sufficient information to your question so it can be solved without going back and forth five times.